# Bash script to check if mdadm is installed if not it will install it

Tags: bash, raid, mdadm

Working on a bash script which first will check if mdadm is installed, if not it will install it. This is my script but it's not working correctly. Hope someone can help me.

```
 if [ "$mdadm" = "mdadm" ]
    then
  echo -e "Mdadm is installed.\n"
   else
   echo -e "Install mdadm .\n"
   aptitude -y install $mdadm

   fi
```

Comment: You don't need to check whether it's installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the needed script (say script.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh

for P; do
    dpkg -s "$P" >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
        echo "$P is installed."
    } || {
        echo "Installing $P"
        aptitude -y install $P
    }
done
```

Usage: **script.sh mdadm**

You can also check for as many packages as you need

Usage: **script.sh mdadm package2 package3 ...**

**EDIT: For only one package you can do the following:**

```
    dpkg -s "mdadm" >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
        echo "mdadm is installed."
    } || {
        echo "Installing mdadm"
        aptitude -y install mdadm
    }
```

Comment: Great, thanks! If you want to specify the package in the script is it to change the p to package name ?

Comment: yes my dear. Simply remove the for loop and replace $P with <yourpackagename>.plz don't forget to upvote the answer.

Comment: If you need it I will edit the answer

Comment: That would be awesome if you could edit the answer. I will surely try to do it my my self, but very unsure.

Comment: @user3185936 check the edit